# How about energy transformation if we are almost on speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, velocity, inertial-frames

Lets say we have a plane that has %99.9999 of light speed (almost $c$). On this plane, can I move? I mean can I do energy transformation? If there is no 'time' on that point how it is possible to energy transformation?

Comment: There absolutely is time for you. Relativity means that, to you, you can always assume you are not moving fast at all and perform physics in your frame the same as if you were standing still on Earth

Comment: Why is there no 'time'? Why is the situation any different from being on a plane at 1000 km/hr? What is 'energy transformation'?

Comment: @JonCuster I mean, for example if I want to press keyboard, I need time to occur this event and I need to transform my energy to another one . It should be different 1000 km/hr vs. speed of light because velocity increased so 'time' should be different, shouldn't ?

Comment: Your frame of reference is that of sitting in the plane. It does not matter if the plane (and you with it) are travelling 0 km/hr, 1000 km/hr, or 99.999% of the speed of light. You are sitting on a plane. Welcome to special relativity...

Comment: First postulate of SR: "The laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames of reference." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postulates_of_special_relativity#Postulates_of_special_relativity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One effect of time dilation and space compression is compensation for this apparent paradox. I call it a paradox because two different observers would disagree about the answer, and both, oddly, would be right.

If I'm floating in a blimp just to one side of the plane's trajectory not moving with respect to the ground, and you asked me if you could walk down the aisle of the plane with some given velocity greater than $c - v_{plane}$, I would say no, you absolutely can not, because then you would be exceeding the universal speed limit.

But if I were instead sitting accross the aisle from you, and you asked me exactly the same question, I would say yes, you absolutely can, because within that frame of reference, it is as if the plane is stationary.

Among other things in [this article](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/37018725/ns/technology_and_science-science/t/stephen-hawkings-time-machine/#.WNE_A_nythE), Stephen Hawking resolves the apparent paradox with a train illustration:

> "Imagine a track that goes right around Earth, a track for a super-fast train. Onboard are passengers with a one-way ticket to the future. The train begins to accelerate, faster and faster. Soon it's circling the Earth over and over again.
>   
> "To approach the speed of light means circling the Earth seven times a second. But no matter how much power the train has, it can never quite reach the speed of light, since the laws of physics forbid it.
>   
> "Instead, let's say it gets close," writes Hawking. "Something extraordinary happens: Time starts flowing slowly on board relative to the rest of the world, just like near the black hole, only more so. Everything on the train is in slow motion."
> (...)
> Say there's a child running forward up the train. "Her forward speed is added to the speed of the train, so couldn't she break the speed limit simply by accident? The answer is no," writes Hawking. "The laws of nature prevent the possibility by slowing down time onboard. Now she can't run fast enough to break the limit. Time will always slow down just enough to protect the speed limit."

(There is a lot of other cool stuff in the article, btw)